# Signal R IDisconnect and IConnected not present in nuget package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.2.0.3 for timer application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I am implementing a timer application using signal r in mvc. I have installed package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.2.0.3 from nuget. But I am not getting interfaces  IDisconnect and IConnected like those present in direct signal r package. Any alternate solution present here so that I can write Connected and Disconnected methods of these interfaces.
I have referred this tutorial from the link :- 
http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=826
I have created hub as below:-

```
public class TimerHub : Hub, Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.IConnection
    {
        public Task Disconnect()
        {
            TimerEventHandler.Instance.Disconnect(Context.ConnectionId);
            return Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).leave(Context.ConnectionId,
                DateTime.Now.ToString());
        }
        public Task Connect()
        {
            string connectionName = Context.ConnectionId;
            if (Context.User != null && Context.User.Identity != null
                && Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                TimerEventHandler.Instance.UpdateCache(
                    Context.User.Identity.Name,
                    Context.ConnectionId,
                    ConnectionStatus.Connected);
                connectionName = Context.User.Identity.Name;
            }
            return Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).joined(connectionName,
                DateTime.Now.ToString());
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SignalR 2.0.3, `OnConnected` and `OnDisconnected` are defined as virtual methods in the `Hub` base class.

You should not try to implment the `IConnection` interface.

Your `TimerHub` should wind up looking like this:

```
public class TimerHub : Hub
{
    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        TimerEventHandler.Instance.Disconnect(Context.ConnectionId);
        return Clients.Caller.leave(Context.ConnectionId,
            DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }

    public override Task OnDisconnected()
    {
        string connectionName = Context.ConnectionId;
        if (Context.User != null && Context.User.Identity != null
            && Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            TimerEventHandler.Instance.UpdateCache(
                Context.User.Identity.Name,
                Context.ConnectionId,
                ConnectionStatus.Connected);
            connectionName = Context.User.Identity.Name;
        }
        return Clients.Caller.joined(connectionName,
            DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }
}
```